# Programmatically determine shape generated by SVG path

Tags: javascript, testing, d3.js, svg, graph

I am working on an open source graphing library that provides high level abstractions over D3. I would like to write integration tests that verify that a pie graph abstraction is actually generating slices, a bar chart is actually generating rectangular bars, etc. As far as I can tell this requires looking at the `d` attribute of the rendered svg path, which contains the serious of commands necessary to draw the element.

For example given the following path I would like to be able to determine what shape it would render (here a "pie slice")

```
<path d="M1.0409497792752502e-14,-170A170,170,0,0,1,109.2738936467117,-130.22755533022627L0,0Z" ></path>
```

I *could* create a dictionary that maps a series of commands to a shape (eg "M A L Z" => "Pie Slice"). However this will not *positively* determine the shape - it's really just a best guess. What I would really like is a way to evaluate the commands and positively determine what shape they would result in. I am more concerned with identifying common graph shapes (circle, rectangle, square, line, etc) than arbitrary shapes ("17 sided object").

**Any suggestions on positively identifying generated shape from SVG path commands?** Haven't been able to find any libraries that may help yet. Open to more general suggestions for how to verify the shapes generated by SVG elements (aside from screenshot comparisons)

Comment: why not screenshot comparisons? (or at least an xor comparison of a bitmapped version to a known correct bitmap?)

Comment: If d3 always generates slices using the sequence MALZ, then that seems like a pretty reliable heuristic.  You could go a step further and check that both ends of the arc are equidistant from the centre of the pie (L coords) -within some small margin of error.  That's pretty much conclusive.

Comment: I've done a lot of `d3` visualizations over the years, and generally bar charts are drawn with `rect`, circles are usually made with `circle`, etc...  To answer your actual question, though, I'd check the angle of *adjacent* L segments.  90 degrees is a rect, < 90 is an arc, no adjacent Ls (meaning only As) is a circle (oval), etc...  *Note*,  adjacent Ls could start with an M and end with an L.

Comment: what is the reverse,, given a shape can i get the svg path

Answer (score 0):

old question, but still open.
I understand that the question makes the problem look difficult, but actually if you want to test your own program, it is fair to assume you know what the correct result should be for a given input test vector and you make a "d" string compare. If you end up testing the sequence of SVG instructions, you end up testing a subset of the output as you would discard the numbers.

The problem you're posing is beyond the scope of SVG unit testing, and is of recognizing shapes of SVG paths generated by a black box. SVG is not a formal shapes descriptor, it can be compared to an instruction set, there are an unbound number of ways to generate the same shape. Imagine I generate an arc then cover it with a rect, you'll see a rect only as a result, is that wrong ? no, is that misleading for something checking the SVG sequence only, yes.

Therefore the suggestion to make the tests on pixel level is probably the only reliable option, and a classification engine would most likely be able to classify the shapes.